# Dovecot - exclude LDAP locked accounts

Tags: dovecot, openldap

I have installed Dovecot with LDAP; everything works fine except that the users I attempted to lock using `pwdAccountLockedTime` are still able to login.

Here is my ldap.conf.ext file:

```
hosts = myldap
dn = cn=admin,dc=home,dc=com
dnpass = mysecret
#auth_bind = no
ldap_version = 3
base = ou=People,dc=home,dc=com
deref = never
scope = subtree
user_attrs =
user_filter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u)
pass_attrs = mail=user,userPassword=password
pass_filter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u))
default_pass_scheme = PLAIN
```

How can I ensure that users with the `pwdAccountLockedTime` attribute will be ignored?

Comment: Is the attribute always _absent_ for active users?

Comment: Yes. This attribute is absent for active users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it into the search filter. Use `(attr=*)` to check for the attribute's existence, and `(!...)` to negate a filter (i.e. check for non-existence).

```
(&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u)(!(pwdAccountLockedTime=*)))
```

Expanded version:

```
(&
  (objectclass=inetOrgPerson)
  (mail=%u)
  (!
    (pwdAccountLockedTime=*)
  )
)
```

Note: Dovecot won't know that the account is locked; it will think it doesn't exist at all.